Raspberry Pi and Mahematica 13 gets stuck in hat=DeviceOpen[“SenseHAT”]
I am using a Raspberry Pi model B+ and Mathematica 13 that installs with Bullseye.
When trying to connect to the Sense Hat CPU goes to 100% for a while and then drops. I never get an output nor an error.
The In[] remains with a filled central dot and never ends.
If I go to wolfram in a terminal I get this:
In[1]:= FindDevices[]                                                                                                                 
/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/13.3/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-ARM64/WolframKernel: symbol lookup error: /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/13.3/SystemFiles/Components/MRAALink/LibraryResources/Linux-ARM64/MRAALink.so: undefined symbol: i2c_smbus_read_byte

But the notebook view does not show anything. A web search with mathematica and MRAALink doesn’t show anything useful.
Any ideas on how to solve this and make it work?
Ah! and this is not working for me. It’s already updated.
Also searching about i2c_smbus_read_byte is not giving anything useful related to mathematica.
The hat is working fine when I use Python.
Thanks!
